# Count frequency of every element in a list using just comparison operators

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I have to count the frequencies of elements in a list and return it in a list of key value pair, where key is the element in the list and value is the number of times it has occurred in the list. For example:

for input `[0,2,2,0,2,5,0,2]` the output should be `[(0,3),(2,4),(5,1)]`

The catch here is we have to do it **without using any predefined functions except comparisons**.

```
import Data.Map (fromListWith, toList)

frequency :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
frequency xs = toList (fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs])
```

This works but toList and fromListWith classifies as predefined functions. Is there any way to do this without using any Data.Map functions?

Comment: are the values always ordered?

Comment: not necessarily

Comment: [0,2,2,0,2,5,0,2] == [(0,3),(2,4),(5,1)].
This might be a better example

Comment: You can always look for definitions of  `toList` and `fromList`.

Comment: Given that `(+)` is *also* a predefined function, it's not clear what the arbitrary restriction covers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
freq:: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
freq []      = []
freq (x: xs) = ins x (freq xs)
   where 
      ins :: (Ord a) => a -> [(a, Int)] -> [(a, Int)]
      ins x ((fk, fv): fs) | x == fk = (fk, fv + 1): fs 
      ins x ((fk, fv): fs) | x <  fk = (x, 1): (fk, fv): fs       
      ins x ((fk, fv): fs)           = (fk, fv): ins x fs             
      ins x []                       = (x, 1): []
```

`ins` function insert single element in map.
it is recursively goes thru the map.

If current element is equal to key it increment the value.

```
ins x ((fk, fv): fs) | x == fk = (fk, fv + 1): fs
```

If current element is less then key it insert new entry in the map.

```
ins x ((fk, fv): fs) | x <  fk = (x, 1): (fk, fv): fs
```

Otherwise (if element is greater) it tries to insert element in tail of the map.

```
ins x ((fk, fv): fs)           = (fk, fv): ins x fs
```

Last part is simply handle case when map is empty.

Comment: You can omit the 2nd and 3rd `ins x ((fk, fv): fs)` and instead use `ins x ((fk, fv): fs) | x == fk = ... | x < fk = ... | otherwise = ...`. Also, it's always a good idea to add a short explanation of the code to beginners, since giving the solution away does not help them (unless they simply want to avoid doing some homework).

Comment: true. i would really appreciate some assistance with the code @talex provided.

Comment: i dont quite understand what fv is. I changed the code to understand as follows:
 ins x ((fk, fv): fs) | x == fk = (fk, fv + 4): fs
so fr a matrix [8,8,9,7,7] we get [(7,5),(8,5),(9,1)]

Comment: I extended my answer a little.